# Loop through $_POST array isn't working

Tags: php, arrays, loops, post

I have a php function that is supposed to loop through an array of $_POST data containing record ids, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it isn't working. I have similar functionality elsewhere in my site, but this particular one want to be difficult:

```
if (isset($_POST['classNumberAdd']) && isset($_POST['classNameAdd'])) {
    $classNumber = $_POST['classNumberAdd'];
    $className = $_POST['classNameAdd'];

    $sqlAddClass = "INSERT INTO classes (className, classNumber) VALUES ('" . $className . "', '" . $classNumber . "')";

    include('../includes/dbConnect.php');

    $addClassResult = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlAddClass);

    // Get the id of the class just inserted            
    $sqlGetClassID = "SELECT classID FROM classes WHERE className = '" . $className . "' AND classNumber = '" . $classNumber . "'";
    $getClassIdResult = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlGetClassID);
    $classID = 0;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getClassIdResult)) {$classID = $row[0];}

    $log->lwrite('Before check if array set: docsToAddToClass array: ' . $_POST['docsToAddToClass']);

    // Add any checked docs to the new class
    if (isset($_POST['docsToAddToClass'])) {

        $log->lwrite('After check if array set and before addDocs function call: docsToAddToClass array: ' . $_POST['docsToAddToClass']);

        foreach($_POST['docsToAddToClass'] as $docID) {
            $log->lwrite('Doc id being added to new class: ' . $docID);
            // Add each class to the document
            $sqlAddClassToDoc = "INSERT INTO classDocs (classDocsClassID, classDocsDocID) VALUES ('" . $classID . "', '" . $docID . "')";

            $resultAddDocToClass = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlAddClassToDoc);
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);
    echo $classID;
}
```

As you can see I have several lines that log where I'm at. I never get to the line "`$log->lwrite('Doc id being added to new class: ' . $docID);`", so for some reason I'm not getting in the array. The last line to get written to the log on any run through is the "After check if array set..." line.

Originally, instead of the foreach loop, I was passing the POST and class id to a function (defined as `function addDocsToClass($docsArray, $classID)`, but that didn't work, so I moved that whole thing into the code as above to troubleshoot.

I've tried setting the $_POST array to a variable first (such as `$docsArray = $_POST['docsToAddToClass'])`) but nothing I've tried so far works.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

**[EDIT]
New information based on closer look at my code:**

I'm calling the above php script in an $.ajax() call, which is passing docsToAddToClass as a comma delimited list of ids retrieved and built by the following lines:

```
$.each($('#docsTable input[name="docsToAddToClass[]"]:checked'), function() {
    docsToAddToClass.push($(this).val());
});
```

As mentioned in a reply below, $_POST['docsToAddToClass'] prints out in my log as 35,36,37, etc. A javascript alert() displays the same output, as well. So I decided to use php explode to build an array to iterate through:

```
$docsArray = explode(',', $_POST['docsToAddToClass']);
```

However, only the first id in the list is getting put into the variable, which ends up NOT being an array, breaking the script.

So, even after discovering all of that, I'm pretty much back at square one!

How do I iterate through the list of ids in $_POST['docsToAddToClass'], when it is formattted as 35,36,37, and get each id as if $_POST were a regular php array?

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that $_POST['docsToAddToClass'] is set, and that it is an array? If it's not an array, the foreach() isn't going to work.

Comment: Well, I'm using "if (isset($_POST...)", so it is there, and the logging lines display $_POST['docsToAddToClass'] as comma separated doc ids (docsToAddToClass array: 38,37). When I first put the POST into a variable ($docArray = $_POST['docsToAddToClass']), then the log simply shows docsToAddToClass array: 1.

Comment: I see my problem: I'm putting the doc ids into docsToAddToClass as comma separated values (35, 36, 37). Which ISN'T an array! I need to split that on the comma and then I can use the ids!  user769573, I guess if you hadn't asked that question, I wouldn't have looked closer at my code and seen the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I finally got it working, but I don't know what I did right! My rep isn't high enough yet to post my own answer, so post it when I am able in case someone else can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much more trial and error I got it working. The problem is, from what I originally posted and the working code I have now, I don't know what I did right!

So, I will post the working, relevant code:
Javascript:

```
var addDocs = 'false';
var docsToAddToClass = new Array();

if ($('input.chkAddDoc:checked').length > 0) {
    addDocs = 'true';

    // Get the ids of the checked docs the user wants to add to the new class
    $.each($('#docsTable input[name="docsToAddToClass[]"]:checked'), function() {
        docsToAddToClass.push($(this).val());
    });
}

alert('docsToAddToClass' + docsToAddToClass);

// Build the string to send as $_POST data
var dataString = 'classNumberAdd=' + classNumberAdd + '&classNameAdd=' + classNameAdd;
if (docsToAddToClass != '') {  dataString += '&docsToAddToClass=' + docsToAddToClass; }
```

And the php script: 
if (isset($_POST['classNumberAdd']) && isset($_POST['classNameAdd'])) {
    $classNumber = $_POST['classNumberAdd'];
    $className = $_POST['classNameAdd'];

```
$sqlAddClass = "INSERT INTO classes (className, classNumber) VALUES ('" . $className . "', '" . $classNumber . "')";

include('../includes/dbConnect.php');

$addClassResult = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlAddClass);

// Get the id of the class just inserted            
$sqlGetClassID = "SELECT classID FROM classes WHERE className = '" . $className . "' AND classNumber = '" . $classNumber . "'";
$getClassIdResult = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlGetClassID);
$classID = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getClassIdResult)) {$classID = $row[0];}

// Add any checked docs to the new class
if (isset($_POST['docsToAddToClass'])) {

    $docsArray = explode(',', $_POST['docsToAddToClass']);

    foreach($docsArray as $docID) {

        // Add each class to the document
        $sqlAddClassToDoc = "INSERT INTO classDocs (classDocsClassID, classDocsDocID) VALUES ('" . $classID . "', '" . $docID . "')";

        $resultAddDocToClass = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlAddClassToDoc);
    }
}
// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($dbc);

echo $classID;
```

}

Hope that helps someone!